# Standard Deviation after removing outlier.

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I am totally new to statistics. I'm learning the basics.

I came upon this question while solving Erwin Kreyszig's exercise on statistics.
The problem is simple. It asks to calculate standard deviation after removing outliers from the dataset.

The dataset is as follows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 10.
What I did is, I found out q<sub>m</sub> = 3. Then $q$<sub>l</sub> $= \frac{1+2}{2} = 1.5$ and $q$<sub>m</sub> $= \frac{4+10}{2} = 7$.

Now, $IQR = 7-1.5 = 5.5$ and $1.5*IQR = 8.25$

So, we can say numbers beyond $1.5 - 5.5 = -4$ and $7 + 5.5 = 12.5$ will be an outlier.

Since there is no outlier, I found out the Standard Deviation of the set which is 3.53.

But, the answer provided is 1.29 which is different from the standard deviation of the set.

Can anyone help me what I missed?

Also, I have another question - we can see with plain eyes 10 is an outlier. But it is not detected here - why?

Comment: Your second question answers the first.  Try calculating the standard deviation excluding the $10$ to get the provided answer

Comment: @Henry Ohh! -_- I'm so stupid.. But what's wrong with the IQR method? Is it not valid for all calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well deciding what's an outlier is somewhat of an art so there's only a fuzzy line here. Still it seems like a good procedure might detect 10 here and based on your book's answer, it seems like the procedure they intended for you to use should delete 10.

So let's think about what could have gone wrong here. My guess is you should have picked 2 and 4 as your first and third quantiles instead of 1.5 and 7. The procdure for deciding quartiles is also not set in stone and results can vary wildly for small sets of discrete data. It's also an established procedure to consider the upper and lower quartile to be the medians of (1,2,3) and (3,4,10) rather than (1,2) and (4,10) as you've done. The first method is a little more robust (but tends to be biased inwards), as this example demonstrates.

Comment: Thanks! This makes some sense. :)

Answer (score 1):

Removing 10 gives the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ with $\overline{x} = \frac{1 + 2 + 3 + 4}{4} = 2.5$. So the standard deviation is $\sqrt{((1 - 2.5)^2 + (2 - 2.5)^2 + (3 - 2.5)^2 + (4 - 2.5)^2))/(4 - 1)} = \sqrt{(2\cdot1.5^2 + 2\cdot0.5^2)/3} = \sqrt{5/3} = 1.29...$.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. But can you say what's wrong with the IQR method and when to use what?

Comment: The IQR is not the same as the standard deviation, it's not wrong, simply not an answer to the question.

Comment: "The IQR is not the same as the standard deviation" - can you elaborate please?

Comment: That's like explaining why a pear is not an apple. Why do you think they are the same?

Comment: No, I don't mean that they are same. What I mean is how are you eliminating 10? spaceisdarkgreen said something that goes well but I didn't get what you did.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misread your post/comment. That is the correct way of eliminating the outlier, I thought you used it to compute the standard deviation.

Comment: So.. will you please add something on how you are finding the outlier and then computing the standard deviation?